Image displacement in Texmaker
When I want to put some images next to each other and then put a text after it, the images displace undesirably (they go after the text). I'm using Texmaker.

texmaker is just the editor you used to write the source so is not involved in the typesetting.  LaTeX only moves images on request, presumably you wrapped the \includegraphics in a figure environment which is a "float" the only purpose of which is to mark the content as an insert that is taken out of the document flow and re-inserted at a suitable point to help with page breaking.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned
